# Script to Export Spotfire Graphic to PowerPoint

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am trying to export an active page to an existing PowerPoint presentation.  I know how to do this from the title bar, but I would like to incorporate this into the IronPython code I am writing so I can do several slides at once.

Thanks,
Joseph

Comment: It looks like the answer by Flux will do the job but for what it's worth you can export all pages at once with the same File -> Export -> Powerpoint and choosing to export `all pages` or `all pages (new page per visualization)`. Python incorporation aside, would this not get you where you want to be or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will open up powerpoint and export one visualisation per page:

```
from System.IO import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualContent
from System.Drawing import Bitmap, Graphics, Rectangle, Point
import clr
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint")
import Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint as PowerPoint

powerpoint = PowerPoint.ApplicationClass()
powerpoint.Visible = True
pres=powerpoint.Presentations.Add()
slideCounter = 1

for visual in Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals:
    #print visual.Title

    #export graphic to temp file
    vc = visual.As[VisualContent]()
    bm = Bitmap(2000, 1200)
    g = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
    r = Rectangle(Point(0,0), bm.Size)
    vc.Render(g, r)
    file = Path.GetTempFileName()
    bm.Save(file)

    #pp setup
    slide=pres.Slides.Add(slideCounter, PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    slideCounter = slideCounter+1
    slide.Shapes.AddPicture((file), False, True, 30, 60, 650, 400)
    title=slide.Shapes.Title
    txt=slide.Shapes.AddTextBox(1,10,500,500,100)
    title.Top=0.1
    obj=slide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange
    obj.Font.Size=24
```

You can loop through pages with:

```
for page in Document.Pages:
    Document.ActivePageReference=page
```

Adjusted from code found here: https://tibbr.tibcommunity.com/tibbr/#!/messages/69369

Comment: I tried the above code and it gives me the below error

File "Spotfire.Dxp.Application", line unknown, in Render File SystemError: Attempt take snapshot on application thread in state 'Executing'.Please help me

Comment: @Aparna Uncheck the "Execute in Transaction" field in the 'Edit Script' menu. Shall help.

Answer (score -1):

They are in Spotfire API's. Each page has a bunch of visualization. Look at the snippet below and you may get an idea.

```
foreach (Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Page page in SpotfireDocument.Pages) 
allVisuals.AddRange(page.Visuals); 
// in my case SpotfireDocument extends {Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Document}
```

But, anybody here knows how to get visual of the entire active page? The above method will give snap of sub-visual on active page, but not the entire page itself.