# How to get the Size and placement of a Visual on a Spotfire page?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am trying to create a script that exports selected pages (through a document property) to a PowerPoint. I can get it to where it exports each visual on a page to a slide by modifying the script found here: ([Script to Export Spotfire Graphic to PowerPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731159/script-to-export-spotfire-g...)).

What I am looking to do is to create a way to export the visuals to a slide where the pngs of the visuals retain the same relative size and position to each other on the slide (basically copying the page in Spotfire to Power point). I have looked through the API (pages class, panels class, etc) for my Spotfire version and the closest thing I can find is "VisualizationAreaSize.Size". From what I can tell is it just gets the size of the total Visualization area and not each individual visual. Does anyone know how I can do this or something pretty similar?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hav you tried using the GUI export tool to create a saved report that is the desired result, then using python to just export that saved report, rather than relying on python to do all the formatting too? If you cant format it like you want in the GUI, chances are you cant do it in python as you can only use the classes and such that Spotfire gives you.

Comment: @MarkP. Do you mean the native export tool under the "File" drop down? When I search GUI using Spotfire's search feature nothing shows up.

Comment: Yes. GUI = Graphic User Interface = The File Dropdown. You can try to manually create an export file there, then use python (or native button functionality in Spotfire) to export it out.